# how to make app full screen when a FragmentDialog is showing

Tags: java, android

i make my app Full Screen but when i create and show a Fragment Dialog it'll exit from Full Screen

i try two way but none working for me , check out code 1 and code 2

code 1 : 
add 
`adding <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>`
to my style.xml
code 2 :
override onShow in Fragment Dialog

```
    @Override
    public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag)
    {
        getDialog().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
        super.show(manager, tag);
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        getDialog().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        getDialog().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
    }
```

nothing happened and my app exit from Full Screen again

Comment: Your class extends of `DialogFragment`?

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez yeap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok , i've got the answer by my own
this piece of code make the problem solved :

```
getDialog().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
getDialog().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility());

getDialog().setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
        //Clear the not focusable flag from the window
        getDialog().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);

        //Update the WindowManager with the new attributes (no nicer way I know of to do this)..
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.updateViewLayout(getDialog().getWindow().getDecorView(), getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Override
    public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag)
    {
        getDialog().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
        super.show(manager, tag);
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        getDialog().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        getDialog().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);

        // add these two line
        getDialog().requestWindowFeature(1);
        getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
    }
```

Comment: i try that , not working :( . my app stop full Screen again

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    // Get existing layout params for the window
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
    // Assign window properties to fill the parent
    params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    params.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes((android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) params);
    // Call super onResume after sizing
    super.onResume()

}
```

Comment: copy paste your code , but still the problem appears :( my action bar is hide from the style.xml but this damn home nav bar show up every time i pop up a Fragment Dialog